# Best way to show the cookie usage in our website

Tags: cookies, web

In our website we are using cookies. What is the best and standard way to expose this information to users. i have referred more famous web sites, they are just added the cookie usage in their privacy policy page and Showed the Privacy policy link at the footer of website.Link name like "Privacy & cookies".

And some rare websites showing the cookie usage message at top of the home page in pop up ask asking user to confirm it.

What will be the right way? Is this really need we to expose this message in pop up at top of web page?

Thanks,
Karthik.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the requirements outside europe, but here there are specific legislations on cookie handling. [See this for more legal details](http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm).

Most website owners show the header asking for acceptance of cookies, but to me this calls for a bad UX. If you can incorporate it into your Privacy policy I would go with this. I guess the question is quite subjective though.